# jquery sortable giving issues when divs floated

Tags: jquery, html, css-float, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following markup on which I am trying to enable jquery sortable:

```
<div>
    <div id="sortable">
        <div style="height:200px;width:400px;border:1px solid black;float:left;">Item 1</div>
        <div style="height:200px;width:400px;border:1px solid black;float:right;">Item 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is my javascript:

```
$(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
```

If I remove the floats and allow the divs to stack, it works fine.  With the floats included and 1 div on each side of the screen, sorting does not work.  In fact, with the placeholder style specified, the placeholder appears to span the entire length of the "row" the 2 divs are sitting on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please see the following for a representative sample that is not working:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kx5C/2

Comment: Sortable is part of jquery ui, are you including jquery ui as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I have all of the relevant scripts included:  jquery-ui-1.8.21 and jquery-1.7.2.

Comment: strange, this seems to be working when I paste your code into jsfiddle.  Can you post your other markup, or your current code into jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify the css for the #sortable div (this example assumes you shrink your item 1 and item 2 divs to 300 px width, you may need to adjust these values to fit your needs)

```
#sortable { width: 700px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }

#item1 { width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #444; }
#item2 { width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #444; }

#sortable > div { float: left; }
```

​

This example seems to be working...

http://jsfiddle.net/gefZm/5/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Based on my layout requirements, I cannot float both divs left.  I need them evenly spaced and centered in the parent div, which will result in something similar to the following edit to your posted example:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kx5C/

Comment: Adding a style for the placeholder further defines the behavior.  Now, when you drag one of the items, you can see the placeholder consumes the entire space, and not just the space for a single item:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kx5C/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `overflow:hidden;` in your div